# Jquery-knob.js throwing error G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement is not a function

Tags: angular, jquery-knob

I'm using jquery.knob.js in angular application. I included the scripts in angular-cli.json like this.

```
"scripts": [
        "assets/app/vendors/js/vendors.min.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.knob.min.js",       
        "assets/app/js/core/app-menu.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
        "assets/js/echarts/echarts.js"
      ],
```

But I'm getting error saying that ERROR TypeError: G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement is not a function.

The knobs are working when I'm reloading the page but sometimes not working when I'm changing routes.

Comment: Are you declaring the var in your typescript?

Comment: I'm getting the script in component like this: 
    `ngAfterViewInit() {
        $.getScript('./assets/js/knob.js');
         }`

Comment: You should need to call `getScript`, jquery-knob should already be an available asset. Try installing the typescript definitions for Knob: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery-knob then using it as you would normally `$('#myDiv').knob();`

Comment: Yes, I already have jquery-knob and I included to get the script in angular-cli scripts section.

Comment: Whoops, I meant *Shouldnt* need to call `getScript`. So you're saying you've installed the knob types with `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery-knob`?

Comment: Yes, I installed the knob types already